# kafka delivery semantic configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wondering if someone can point in the right direction on how to
configure kafka for at-least-once delivery, because the default is at-most-once.

What are the configuration parameters needed for it?

Comment: Hi, please have a look in this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-clients-at-most-once-at-least-once-exactly-o)

Comment: @vpa2 hello thanks